# Can you import a C++ class into any Obj-C header?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have some 3rd party source that I'm trying trying to integrate in my app. Much of the code is in C++, and it works fine in their samples. I copied that original code into my project, and now it fails, because it's seeing C++ in an Obj-C header.

UPDATE:

The source code file in question is called "SampleApplicationSession.mm", and it's associated "SampleApplicationSession.h". SampleApplicationSession.h imports C++ headers, and exports several methods that use types found in those headers, like this:

- (void) onQCARUpdate: (QCAR::State *) state;

If I import the C++ header that contains these types, I get the error:

Unknown type name 'namespace'

So in spite of the code being a .mm, it seems that the compiler is not recognizing the header as being Obj-C++ as well.

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get some kind of error message?

Comment: More likely that the header is included from more than one file, including files that are plain Objective-C.

Comment: Have you tried passing the option `-ObjC++` to the clang compiler?

Comment: Wait, does it make a difference that the imported C++ file, Matricies.h, has no associated cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with QCAR::State is that it isn't going to compile with C or plain Objective-C code. Here's a solution that I have used in a similar situation:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
typedef QCAR::State QCARState;
#else
typedef struct QCARState__ QCARState;
#endif

- (void)onQCARUpdate:(QCARState *)state;
```

Now each language is happy. You can even have plain C code passing around QCARState* pointers. Or if you have a property of type QCARState* you can write in plain Objective-C code

```
someObject.qcarState = otherObject.qcarState
```

and it works. Just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, OK, got it.

This is really a compiler error message problem. The problem is not the file that it is claiming is the problem, it's the file *importing* that file.

So I was trying to fix SampleApplicationSession.h, while it was actually mapVC.m that was causing it. Simply commenting out that one import caused the problem to go away.

Now the obvious solution would be to rename mapVC.m to mapVC.mm, but that caused all sorts of errors to come up in formerly working code - even without the import. I guess I'll bludgeon my way through that...

Comment: Does mapVC call methods with C++ classes?

Comment: Only indirectly, it refers to a UIView subclass that contains a single C++ type (the matrix).